# Escaped Ruby regular expression gives no match when used as a literal regexp. Why?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, escaping

Code says it all:

```
teststring = "helloworld$"
string_from_user = "world$"
regexp = Regexp.escape(string_from_user) # assigns "world\\$"
p teststring =~ Regexp.new(regexp) # prints 0 => match found
p teststring =~ /regexp/ # prints nil => no match
```

That the first one matches is mentioned in the [Regexp.escape](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) docs.
But why doesn't the second version match?

I'm concerned because I need to pass this regexp to third party Ruby code. The string comes from the user, so I want to escape it. Then, in some situations, I might add additional regexp symbols to this user's string. For example, I might pass `"^helloworld\\$"` so that third party code would match strings like `"helloworld$othercontent"`.

I am worried that if the third party code uses `=~ /regexp/` instead of `=~ Regexp.new(regexp)`, I will be in trouble, because there will be no match as indicated by the code above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `/regexp/` is a regexp matching the string `"regexp"`. Perhaps you meant `/#{regexp}/`?

**Edit:** I take it, from reading your question more fully, that you're passing a string into third party code that you know will be making a Regexp from that string. In which case, you should be safe. As noted above, `/regexp/` cannot possibly be what they're doing, because it's just *wrong*. They must be using `Regexp.new()` or something similar.

Comment: Oh my! :))) That's it. Silly me. Thank you :)))